# How do I use .PARAMETER when writing PowerShell help?

Tags: powershell

How do I use the .PARAMETER option to add detailed information for the parameters of a function when writing the help for it? I tried ".PARAMETER $ParamName", that didn't work, and I tried ".PARAMETER -ParamName", that didn't work either.

Here's an example:

```
<#

.SYNOPSIS
short overview

.DESCRIPTION

longer overview

.PARAMETER

dont know how this works?

.EXAMPLE

Example code 

.NOTES

This is awesome!

.LINK

http://winfred.com
#>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not complicated, you simply use it as:

```
.PARAMETER NameOfParam
    Description of param
```

For example:

```
.PARAMETER MyParam
    MyParam does whatever bla bla bla...
```

Comment: Also see: `help about_Comment_Based_Help`

Comment: A variant (that I prefer) is to put an explanatory comment immediately above the parameter definition. It will then automatically be included as parameter description in the help text.

Comment: And if you want multiple parameters, you'll just add another `.PARAMETER MyOtherPara` line/block